# Sync Framework -When is tombstone updated?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2014, microsoft-sync-framework

[image]

I use SQL Server 2014 for all databases and Sync Framework 2.1 in all layers.
The weird thing is suddenly records are deleted from somewhere without user interaction. I thoroughly suspect that this happens due to synchronization but cannot figure it out. I know when the tombstone is set to 1, records will treated as deleted hence the record is deleted. How could this deletion may happens? Please help me with this.

Answer (score 1):

the tracking tables (records what has changed) are updated via triggers on the table you're synching. so the deleted flag will only get set if someones delete a row that you're synching. you may want to check other apps/user accessing your database who may be potentially deleting rows.

Comment: thank Junet, this deleting happens on a specific data set which were inserted by executing a SQL script in Branch 1. I found that ,these set of data (about 200 records) are not synced to any other Branch also (no records in Tracking tables in other Branches) , and if any update done in Branch 1, when the sync starts, it tries to delete the updated record.

Comment: @user1220497 Did you find the solution, we have encountered same issue.